# Trying to send mail alert for mysql

Tags: mysql

how to send mail alert for MySQL?

can we send alerts when the MySQL has large number of connections, or MySQL is not responding properly. Can someone help me to solve this prolem ?

Comment: I don't think there is any automated function for that, you will probably need to create a script or small program that monitor that parameter and send an email.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this in a number of ways. `SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST;` query would give you information about the number of connections as well as the queries being executed by each connection(thread). A sample result is as follows.

```
mysql> SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST;
+------+------+--------------------+------+---------+------+-------+-----------------------+
| Id   | User | Host               | db   | Command | Time | State | Info                  |
+------+------+--------------------+------+---------+------+-------+-----------------------+
| 1298 | root | 192.168.1.76:37648 | NULL | Sleep   |    0 |       | NULL                  |
| 1491 | root | localhost          | NULL | Query   |    0 | init  | show full processlist |
+------+------+--------------------+------+---------+------+-------+-----------------------+
```

If you are only concerned with the number of current connection(threads) you can use the following query.

```
mysql> SHOW STATUS WHERE `variable_name` = 'Threads_connected';
+-------------------+-------+
| Variable_name     | Value |
+-------------------+-------+
| Threads_connected | 2     |
+-------------------+-------+
```

Now about the mail alerts, you can setup a cron job(shell script) to fire a mail alert as soon as the number of current connections exceed a certain limit. `mail` command can be used for this.

```
$ echo "Max MySQL Connections reached"| mail -s "your subject" your@email.com
```

Also, I came across a great MySQL Monitoring tool- [MONyog](https://www.webyog.com/product/monyog). It would let you setup mail alerts for any of the MySQL variable.